# Does a Gmail account ever expire?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account and I never login by visiting Gmail's website. However, I do check emails via a custom script which does need a username and password.

Is there an expiry date on my account?

What would that be if there was? As I access my account via script I was wondering if that would that be counted as an activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Gmail accounts ***may*** expire if they aren't used in 9 months. Beyond that, it is up to Google's discretion whether they choose to delete accounts or not. There is no guarantee of that.

As for the script, you should check the '[Last account activity](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=45938)' in Gmail. It shows you information about recent activity in your mail. Recent activity includes any time that your mail was accessed using a regular web browser, a POP1 client, a mobile device, etc. They will list the IP address that accessed your mail, the associated location, as well as the time and date.

To see your account activity, click the **Details** link next to the **Last account activity** line at the bottom of any Gmail page. Using this information, you can confirm if your script is counted as an activity.

Comment: ah yes .. 'last account activity' - greate point.. I've just checked it and can see IMAP in the activity. so I'd assume that'll keep my account active. Cheers.